# Image won't show from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the image based on the path which is retrieved from mySQL.  The file path is correct yet it doesn't display.

My code is

```
echo '<td><img src="' .$img_path .$row['image'].'" width="150" height="25" alt="'.$row['date_added'].'" /></td>';
```

and it outputs this.

```
<img width="150" height="25" alt="2014-01-01 15:52:20" src="localhost/website/content/images/profile/test.png"></img>
```

also it outputs `</img>` instead of `/>` Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: add more code for better understand your problem

Comment: Your `src` contains a relative link, rather than a fixed path to your image, I suspect it's breaking there.

Comment: try $img_path = "http://".$img_path; before echo this img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `http://` to path of image as follow:

```
echo '<td><img src="http://' .$img_path .$row['image'].'" width="150" height="25" alt="'.$row['date_added'].'" /></td>';
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that.  I was thinking my file path was coming from the root directory and missed I had it in another folder!

Comment: @ServerSideSkittles you should accept this answer if its what you wanted and solved your problem.